# Where is the user model in airflowmodels?

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to set up my own authentication method in Airflow. However, part of it needs to refer to the user module but it isn't present in my installation of Airflow.

Also, in authentication doc's of Airflow they keep referring to a "user" module. For example see below.

```
# navigate to the airflow installation directory
$ cd ~/airflow
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 10 2015, 03:28:08)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
user = PasswordUser(models.User())
```

However, in the airflow module folders (/lib/python.../dist-packages/airflow/models/...) there is no user module. In the airflow docs this user module is also not mentioned:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/index.html

However, there is a sourcecode page with this module:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.9/_api/airflow/models/user/index.html

Is it legacy perhaps? Hopefully someone knows.

Comment: Which version of Airflow are you using? In 2.5.3 (the latest) the SqlAlchemy model that seems to be the closes to what you are using is in (airflow/www/fab_security/sqla/models.py)[https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/cb842dd8aa8749b4d0a474c6e2fda11505d9ba99/airflow/www/fab_security/sqla/models.py#L143] Some other documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.3/administration-and-deployment/security/access-control.html#user)

Comment: Ah, it seems that they moved it there and the changed the structure quite a bit. Thank you.